# Is there a Rails equivalent of Sinatra's 'register'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I'm in the process of creating a rubygem which will be used with both Sinatra and Rails applications. Ideally, I'd like to have a single gem which can work with both frameworks. It's very simple - it provides some helpers, styles, scripts and view partials.

For Sinatra, I use the [`register`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#extending-the-dsl-class-context-with-sinatraregister) method to register the module, which in turn adds the helpers, adds some entries to the load paths and optionally creates some actions/routes. So far so good.

My question is: What is the rails equivalent of this? Engines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to define routes, I think a rails engine would work best.

You can load helpers with railties too, but I don't think it's possible to define routes with railties.

Rails Engines:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Railties:
http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html

Comment: I'd actually forgotten about Railties (even though Engines are really Railties with extra bits). I will use a railtie for the current implementation, since I don't need routes after all, but I understand the distinction properly now. Thank you!